# One generic import or multiple specific imports?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class which uses the following from the package `java.io`: `FileOutputStream`, `OutputStream`, `FileInputStream`, `File`, and `IOException`. Should I use a generic import, `import java.io.*`, or should I import each class individually.

What is the difference between a generic import and multiple imports?

Comment: As best practice its better to use multiple imports instead of generic import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, but if there are two classes with same names in different packages will give a compile error